# Divergence of series $\sum \frac{k}{2k+1}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Consider the infinite series denoted by:
$$\sum \frac{k}{2k+1}$$
starting at some arbitrary index. We wish to prove that this diverges. We will see what the limit of the general term  $a_n$ is, if this does not go to zero, the series diverges by the limit test.
$$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{k}{2k+1}=\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{k}}= \frac{1}{2+0}=\frac{1}{2}$$
By using the fraction limit theorem $(\lim \frac{A}{B}= \frac{\lim A}{\lim B})$ and sum limit theorem respectively. We conclude that the series diverges as $a_n 
 \not \rightarrow 0$.

Is this correct?
I wanted to also try the following proof for $k\geq 1$:

$$ \frac{k}{2k+1} > \frac{1}{2k+1} \geq \frac{1}{2k+k} = \frac{1}{3} \frac{1}{k} $$
Now we simply get the harmonic series, but every factor is multiplied by $\frac{1}{3}$, is there still some result we can use about multiplying divergent series by nonzero nonnegative constants?

Comment: That first proof looks good, and is how I would solve this problem.

Comment: Both ways are fine, but what do you mean with "the fraction limit theorem"?

Comment: One of the standard results for limits is that if we take a limit of a fraction of two sequences, it is the same as the fraction of limits.

Comment: @WesleyGroupshaveFeelingsToo Ah ok you are referring to that one $$ \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{k}}$$ That's fine!

Comment: In my book a friendly introduction to analysis by Kosmala, it is referred to 2.2.1C

Comment: Yeah, we simply set the original sequence in the enumerator to 1 in this main theorem and the result follows.

Comment: @WesleyGroupshaveFeelingsToo Yes of course I didn't realized at first you were referring to the first limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct since $a_n \not \to 0$ the series does not converges and since it is with positive terms it diverges to $+\infty$.

Also the alternative way is fine.

Comment: Is it fine because a sum is the limit of partial sums and for limits we know that a divergent limit to $\infty$, times any positive constant still is a divergent limit?

Comment: in maths: $\{ s_n \} \rightarrow \infty  $ then  for $c>0$, also $\{ c s_n \} \rightarrow \infty $

Comment: @WesleyGroupshaveFeelingsToo Yes my observation is aimed to stress that form $a_n \not \to 0$ we can conclude in general that the series "does not converges" and in taht particular case it diverges to $\infty$. I prefer use that distinction since we can also have the possibility of bounded but not convergent series.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use the following $${k\over 2k+1}\ge {k\over 3k}={1\over 3}$$for $k\ge 1$ which implies a direct divergence. Still, your proof sounds right to me.

Comment: Too quick on getting rid of the initial $k$ haha.

Comment: Thanks, that was useful.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck!